# Color test finishes but no console or gui for Ubuntu Server 64

Tags: boot, boot-issues, ubuntu

I've used the **Raspberry Pi Imager** utility to download and install **Ubuntu Server 20.04 x64** on an SD card, and added `hdmi_force_hotplug=1` to `usercfg.txt` before booting up.

This worked just fine for Raspbian OS (except the file modified in that case was `config.txt`) and yet, I don't get a console or any output whatsoever after the four-pixel color test appears and disappears.

The monitor does not go to sleep - it maintains a blank screen and an **active display**.  I can still shut it down with `Alt+Fn+SysRq+O` but nothing else produces any output, only the low-level BIOS shortcuts like SysRq and `CTRL+ALT+DEL` trigger any response.

I apologise if this question has been answered, I was not able to find it.  Could anyone suppose what mistake I am making?

Troubleshooting attempted

- I've tried adding a static IP to the netconfig (optional: true) and
  SSH is 'not able to find a route.'  Notably I did not add an `ssh`
  file to the boot partition at the time.
- I've tried more specific HDMI settings, forcing it to my native resolution with reduced blanking - no change.
- I've deleted the Imager's cache and re-downloaded / re-verified the SD card, with the same results.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought it would be funnier to answer my question than delete it - switching the HDMI port helps!

Comment: so it's a raspberry pi 4?